# CLR-based UDT and string property in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

Is there absolutely no way to have a property of a string type as part of CLR-based UDT? I know strings are non-blittable, but I really need one are there any tricks allowing to squeeze through that limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link contains the answer (Figure 5), which is implementing your own serializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164013.aspx